# Quiero acceder a todos los registros, no importa si hay campos vacíos

Tags: php, mysql, while

Se recuperaron  resultados del listado de clientes

```
    echo "<table><tr class='header_table1'><td class='field'>Id Usuario</td><td class='field'>Nombre</td><td class='field'>Email</td><td class='field'>Celular</td><td class='field'>Dirección</td><td class='field'>Estado de cuenta</td></tr>";
    while($array1=mysqli_fetch_row($resultset1)){ 
        $query2 = "SELECT celular FROM celular WHERE idUsuario = '$array1[0]'";
        $resultset2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
        while($array2=mysqli_fetch_row($resultset2)){
         $query3="SELECT email FROM email WHERE idUsuario = '$array1[0]'";
            $resultset3 = mysqli_query($connection, $query3);
            while($array3=mysqli_fetch_row($resultset3)){
                $query4="SELECT estadoCuenta, idCliente FROM cliente WHERE idUsuario = '$array1[0]'";
                $resultset4 = mysqli_query($connection, $query4);
                while($array4=mysqli_fetch_row($resultset4)){
                    $query5="SELECT direccion, ciudad, departamento FROM residencia WHERE idCliente = '$array4[1]'";
                    $resultset5 = mysqli_query($connection, $query5);
                    while($array5 = mysqli_fetch_row($resultset5)){
                      echo "<tr><td class='field'>$array1[0]</td><td class='field'>$array1[1] $array1[2] $array1[3]</td><td class='field'>$array3[0]</td><td class='field'>$array2[0]</td><td class='field'>$array5[0] $array5[1], $array5[2]</td><td class='field'>$array4[0]</td></tr>";
                    }
                }
            }
       }
    }
    ?>
```

Cuando ejecuto estos ciclos, sólo estoy obteniendo los registros que tiene la información completa. ¿Sabes qué debería modificar? Intenté ejecutarlos sin anidarlos pero no me dejan imprimirlos en pantalla de la manera en que necesito.

Estos son los resultados obtenidos después de ejecutar las consultas anidadas en los ciclos while:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y estos son los resultados que tiene la tabla y debería mostrar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No necesitas anidar bucles, sino utilizar `JOIN`, tal que así:

```
SELECT * FROM cliente
  JOIN celular USING(idUsuario)
  JOIN email USING(idUsuario)
  JOIN residencia USING(idUsuario);
```

Y recorrer la consulta con un único bucle `while`:

```
echo '<table><tr class="header_table1">'
    .'<td class="field">Id Usuario</td>'
    .'<td class="field">Nombre</td>'
    .'<td class="field">Email</td>'
    .'<td class="field">Celular</td>'
    .'<td class="field">Dirección</td>'
    .'<td class="field">Estado de cuenta</td>'
    .'</tr>';
$rs = $connection->query("
    SELECT * FROM cliente
      JOIN celular USING(idUsuario)
      JOIN email USING(idUsuario)
      JOIN residencia USING(idUsuario);
");
while($r = $rs->fetch_assoc()) 
    echo '<tr>'
        .'<td class="field">'.$r['idUruario'].'</td>'
        .'<td class="field">'.$r['nombreUsuario'].' '.$r['primerApellido'].''.$r['segundoApellido'].'</td>'
        .'<td class="field">'.$r['email'].'</td>'
        .'<td class="field">'.$r['celular'].'</td>'
        .'<td class="field">'.$r['direccion'].' '.$r['ciudad'].' '.$r['departamento'].'</td>'
        .'<td class="field">'.$r['estadoCuenta'].'</td>'
        .'</tr>';
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, fue más sencillo como lo mencionó.